# CommandParameter not working in ListView

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm new to winRT and struggling a lot with this.

I have created a DemoViewModel in which I declare a DemoClickCommand like below. The Command is of Type DelegateCommand.

```
public DelegateCommand DemoClickCommand { get; private set; }

protected virtual void OnClickCommandExecuted(object parameter)
    {
      var obj = parameter;
    }

    protected virtual bool OnClickCommandCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return true;
    }

public DemoViewModel()
    {
      this.DemoClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnClickCommandExecuted, this.OnClickCommandCanExecute);
    }
```

I have bound this command to a button on my form which works fine on its own but does not work when contained in a listView which uses a datatemplate.

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<!-- THIS BUTTON WORKS FINE-->    
<Button Content="Button"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="143"
            Margin="1354,424,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="307"
            Background="#FFC11A1A"
            FontSize="36"
            Command="{Binding DemoClickCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
<!-- THIS LISTVIEW WHICH USES THE DATATEMPLATE WONT WORK -->
    <ListView x:Name="lvDemoItems"
              SelectionChanged="lvDemoItems_SelectionChanged"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Margin="0,140,0,0"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DemoTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DemoItems}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Width="904">
    </ListView>

  </Grid>
```

This is the data template defined in my page resources

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="DemoTemplate">
      <Grid Height="110"
            Width="480"
            Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                Width="110"
                Height="110">
          <Image Source="{Binding ImageURI}"
                 Stretch="UniformToFill"
                 AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="10,0,0,0">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                     Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"
                     TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                     Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"
                     MaxHeight="160" />
          <Button Content="Edit"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  Background="Green"
                  Height="40"
                  Width="80"
                  Margin="0,20,0,0"
                  Command="{Binding DemoClickCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

  </Page.Resources>
```

I think I need to use Attached Dependency Properties but not sure how to implement this.

This is what I have so far but I am not sure how to make it work. Can you please help and explain this? Thanks

```
public ICommand DemoClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DemoClickCommand =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DemoClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Button), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemCommandPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnClickCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ICommand command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF value inheritance done from bottom to top. For example when you set a specific font to a Stack Panel and all the child controls inside the stack panel would get the same font by default. In your snippet with datatemplate, you have a Button binded to DemoClickCommand, which is child to ListView control where ItemsSource is **DemoItems**. DemoItems don't have a Property called DemoClickCommand. So you need to explicitly mention the Ancestor Type for the button. Please try the below XAML snippet in your DataTemplate code

```
<Button Content="Edit"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              Background="Green"
              Height="40"
              Width="80"
              Margin="0,20,0,0"
              Command="{Binding Path=DemoClickCommand, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />
```

Or you can do the same using BindingElementName property. Give a name for your ManGrid and use

```
<Button Content="Edit"
          BorderBrush="Black"
          Background="Green"
          Height="40"
          Width="80"
          Margin="0,20,0,0"
          Command="{Binding ElementName="MyGrid" Path=DemoClickCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. What I did find was if the button is wrapped around the grid it works but when the button is inside of the Grid or StackPanel it does not work. I do not want to make the whole template a button so this approach wont work for me. Thanks

Comment: in your snippet already button control inside the DataTemplate. You have to just mention the ElementName or AncestorType for binding. Plese see my updated answer. Thanks

Comment: Do you know if I can use this in Windows Store apps? RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}} Thanks

Comment: I've tried this but it does not work either: Command="{Binding Path=DemoClickCommand, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've added the DataTemplate inside the ListView.ItemTemplate and change your suggestion to this: Command="{Binding ElementName=lvDemoItems, Path=DataContext.DemoClickCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" and now it works fine!!!